# Entity was not found

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

I am having troubles with only 1 class in symfony2,
Every time i try to use the entity in a template it says the entity was not found.
However everything works perfectly fine on localhost (both dev and prod environment work), but it all stops working when i deploy it on the remote webserver.

I restarted httpd already and tried different methods.

The Entity UserApplication has an association on the Application entity, i am trying to get the name from the application trough the UserApplication in my template file

This is the error message i is throwing,

> [ERROR]: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a
>   template ("Entity was not found.") in
>   "MyBundle:Application:applications_user.html.twig" at line 34. with
>   code: 0 (file: mylocation/20131209193528/app/cache/prod/classes.php,
>   line: 4485)

Snippet: applications_user.html.twig

```
{% extends 'MaximCMSBundle:Default:index.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="page">
        <h3 class="page-header">Applications</h3>
        <div class="page-content">
            <ul class="menu menu-clean">
                {% for application in applications %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('application_view', {'id' : application.id, 'name' : application.application.name}) }}"><span>{{ application.application.name }}</span></a>
                    </li>
                {% else %}
                    <p>There are no open applications at the moment</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Entity UserApplication

```
<?php

namespace MyName\Module\ApplicationBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UserApplication
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_application")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserApplication {
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var json_array $details
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="details", type="json_array", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $details;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $date
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $date;

    /**
     * @var integer $denied
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="denied", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $denied = 0;

    /**
     * @var Application
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application", inversedBy="userApplications")
     */
    protected $application;

    /**
     * @param Application $application
     */
    public function setApplication($application)
    {
        $this->application = $application;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application
     */
    public function getApplication()
    {
        return $this->application;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $date
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $denied
     */
    public function setDenied($denied)
    {
        $this->denied = $denied;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getDenied()
    {
        return $this->denied;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User $user
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\json_array $details
     */
    public function setDetails($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * @return \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\json_array
     */
    public function getDetails()
    {
        return $this->details;
    }

    public function getApplicationEntityName()
    {
        return "MyNameModuleApplicationBundle:Application";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Entity Application:

```
<?php

namespace MyName\Module\ApplicationBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * MyName\Module\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="application")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Application
{
    const FIELD_NAME = "NAME";
    const FIELD_TYPE = "TYPE";

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     *
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Rank
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\MyName\MyBundle\Entity\Rank")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rank_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $rank;

    /**
     * @var Website
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\MyName\MyBundle\Entity\Website")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="website_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $website;

    /**
     * @var string $name
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="application_name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var string $enabled
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="application_enabled", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $enabled = 0;

    /**
     * @var array $fields
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="application_fields", type="json_array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $fields;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserApplication", mappedBy="application")
     */
    protected $userApplications;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->date = new \DateTime("now");
        $this->userApplications = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $enabled
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->enabled = $enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEnabled()
    {
        return $this->enabled;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\Rank $rank
     */
    public function setRank($rank)
    {
        $this->rank = $rank;
    }

    /**
     * @return \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\Rank
     */
    public function getRank()
    {
        return $this->rank;
    }

    /**
     * @param \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\Website $website
     */
    public function setWebsite($website)
    {
        $this->website = $website;
    }

    /**
     * @return \MyName\MyBundle\Entity\Website
     */
    public function getWebsite()
    {
        return $this->website;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $fields
     */
    public function setFields($fields)
    {
        $this->fields = $fields;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFields()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }

    function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $userApplications
     */
    public function setUserApplications($userApplications)
    {
        $this->userApplications = $userApplications;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUserApplications()
    {
        return $this->userApplications;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried running `app_dev` on remote host?

Comment: Yes it gives me the same problem, i do not why but on localhost everything works

Comment: What is the exact message? How did you do the deployment?

Comment: I deployed using Capifony, The files are located at the correct position on the server, i also restarted the httpd service to make sure apc cache was cleared. I added the exact message as an update to my original post

Comment: Ah I thought that by "Entity" you meant "some entity" but now I see that is an actual message. Can you please update you question with snippet of `applications_user.html.twig` containing the line `#34`?

Comment: Thats also a problem, the file only contains 18 lines (it extends from index.html.twig but that doesnt contain a reference to the entity thats missing), to be sure i updated the original message with my snippet

Comment: There is something very, very wrong with you deploy box, I would say. If you haven't tried, can you **completely** delete `releases` directory and run deployment again? Be sure **not to delete** `shared` directory...

Comment: Also, it you have ran `app_dev` on you remote host, why would it crash while referencing `app/cache/prod/...`?? `prod` here doesn't make any sense...

Comment: To fix the app_dev i have to get this sorted first: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451920/authenticationcredentialsnotfoundexception-the-security-context-contains-no-aut) However i am quite certain that it will throw the same error in the dev environment, i just cant figure out why...

Comment: have you tried the obvious php app/console cache:clear -e prod? Your deployment procedure will probably do this, but it's worth a shot. Have you also tried production environment locally? Have you tried enabling debug in production?

Comment: I have tried, 1. deleting the current and releases directory, this fixed the app_dev.php not working issue. I also tried clearing both caches multiple times but this didn't fix the entity not found issue. Running the application in dev mode also throws the same error message as in production. However in dev mode it says the entity was not found but then on line 10 in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apparently had existing records which were conflicting with the application, after deleting those everything worked as supposed to. That was the reason why it was working on the development environment and not in the production.

Thanks for all the support